# Problem with Chessbase 16 - Adding a subline via copy-paste

Tags: chessbase

Sometimes, in Chessbase, when I want to paste a game into another game (to reference it or to analyze a subline), a bug occurs: the pasted game completely overwrites the game I was working on. Why is that?
Nevertheless, I added the move to analyze before pasting the game to prevent it from being overwritten.
There are things where it works (most of the time), but sometimes, it doesn't work even if I restart Chessbase.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the typical copy/paste maneuvers in Chessbase. When I want to copy one game to another, I just drag one game into the other. The copy/paste action happens naturally. If you have an open database, just click and drag the game you want into the other game screen. It should be automatic. If you have two game views open, I think you can do the same thing. If you click the game and hold for a second, the mouse button usually changes into a plus sign, I think. Once that happens, you're good to go with adding the game.